# assign ref to variable in react-native

Tags: typescript, react-native

I'm creating a snake-game with React-Native. I followed the tutorial on https://medium.com/@tamasszikszai/building-snake-with-react-native-game-engine-bbc8abfdebda. However when I write the following, I get a ts-2304-error:

> Cannot find name 'engine':

```
function App() {
  engine: GameEngine;
  return (
    <View>
      <GameEngine 
        ref={ r => engine = r } // ts 2304
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

I also tried `r => { this.engine = r; }`. However that game me this error:

> 'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type
> annotation.ts(2683)

How can I set he `engine`-variable to my DOM-ref?